# Как указать CLR ссылаться на сборку новой версии, без перекомпиляции приложения?

Tags: c#, assembly, gac

Возникла задача: заставить среду CLR ссылаться на сборку новой версии, без перекомпиляции приложения.

Есть некая сборка `TestLib` с классом Test

```
public class Test
{
    public void Work() { Console.WriteLine("Ver 1"); }
}
```

Для тестирования, в методе `Work` выводится номер версии сборки, которая совпадает с настоящей версией сборки (для наглядности).

Сборка с версией 1.0.0.0 добавлена в GAC с помощью утилиты *gacutil.exe*.

Создано приложение, которое ссылается на сборку этой версии, и запускает метод Work() новосозданного объекта. Выводится ver 1.

Теперь в сборку были внесены изменения. Она благополучно получила версию 2.0.0.0, метод Work() соответственно приобрел вид `public void Work() { Console.WriteLine("Ver 2"); }`. Добавил с помощью gacutil.exe в кеш.

Поскольку перекомпилировать приложение не требуется, а назначить зависимость на новую сборку нужно, требуется изменить файл *имя_исполняемого_файла.ехе.config*(находится в том же каталоге, что и исполняемый файл), что и было сделано.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="TestLib" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

По идее, теперь при запуски исполняемого файла, должно выводиться ver 2, но выводится старое сообщение. Видимо приложение до сих пор ссылается на старую версию сборки.

В отладчике видно, что приложение загружает старую версию из GAC:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что могло пойти не так?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPD: для конкретно этого случая: вы прописали в конфиге public key `b77a5c561934e089`. Это PK для для сборки System.dll. Это заведомо неверное значение. Вместо него надо вписать реальный public key вашей сборки TestLib, судя по скрину, правильный ключ - `8af094dc79834699`. Узнать его можно выполнив

до установки сборки:

```
sn -T TestLib.dll
```

после установки сборки.

```
gacutil /l TestLib
```

---

Общий ответ:

1. Вы могли поставить референс на неподписанную версию TestLib, и приложение всегда загружает ее из своей папки.
2. Вы могли неправильно назвать файл .config.
3. Вы могли неправильно вбить public key.
4. Вы могли подписать разные версии разными private key.

Проверьте вывод `dir` в папке приложения - файл конфига должнен быть назван по шаблону SomeApplication.exe.config.

Проверьте вывод `gacutil /l TestLib` - должно быть две записи которые отличаются только версией. Скопируйте оттуда public key и проверьте на точное совпадение.

Запустите приложение под отладчиком, открыть окно Debug / Windows / Modules и найти там откуда и какая версия TestLib загружена. Если загружена из GAC - то в пути будет и версия и public key.

Сами по себе у вас шаги полностью правильные, значит просто где-то чуть-чуть ошиблись.

Comment: Пункты 1-3 соблюдены 100%. Пункт 4: .snk файл с private ключом находится в корневом каталоге проекта. Создавался с помощью UI в Visual Studio (Подписывание сборки). P.S. [Скрин с  путем с версией](http://i.imgur.com/fbv1yh1.png) (Версия на скрине отличается - на данный момент версия, указанная в студии 4.0, пытаюсь явно указать конфигом на версию 5.0 - количество версий увеличилось из-за моих отчаянных попыток всё-таки решить проблему :) ). Такое ощущение, будто CLR каким-то образом игнорирует конфиг файл, в лоб загружая только указанную в студии сборку.

Comment: @pandal кстати, на скрине видно что public key начинается с **8af094**. а у вас в конфиге **b77a5c561934e089**. как вы проверяли пункт (3)? `gacutil /l TestLib` какой public key показывает?

Comment: @pandal обновил ответ

Comment: Точно, копировал ключ mscorlib, и постоянно сверял с ним. Благодарю за вашу внимательность.